# How to set preferIPv4Stack property for JNLP app?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

I need to set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to an app started via JNLP (javaws and applet)

Tried those, without luck...

```
<j2se ...java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" />
<property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
```

The only way i could make it work was seeting when launching javaws from local filesystem:

```
javaws -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true myapp.jnlp
```

What is not possible on a applet or URL.

How should i set this property?

Comment: Best almost-answer so far: http://blog.brixandersen.dk/2007/04/29/working-around-buggy-java-applets/

Comment: Disabling IPV6 on my machine also got JGroups working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Java 7 Update 6 (b17) the list of secure properties has been updated. See [Bug Report 716069](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7160619) for further Details.

You can include this setting by specifying the following line within the resource tag:

`<property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 1):

The only properties that you can set in the JNLP are those [considered secure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) which do not include `java.net.preferIPv4Stack`.

The alternative options you have are (not tested):

- pass the parameter directly to javaws like you did: `javaws -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true myapp.jnlp`
- Java Control Panel > Java > View > Runtime Parameters, but that is a global setting for all webstart applications and applets using the version of the JRE for which you changed the setting
- use an environment variable: `JAVAWS_VM_ARGS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
- flag the setting as secure by adding a line to the [deployment.properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html), located in the Deployment Home(*) : `deployment.javaws.secure.properties=java.net.preferIPv4Stack` - note: not sure if this is available Java > 1.5.

The first 3 options are detailed in [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html).

<sub>(*) Deployment Home:

Windows XP: `%HOME%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment`

Windows 7/Vista: `%APPDATA%\..\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment`

Linux/Solaris: `%HOME%/.java/deployment`</sub>

Comment: The problem is you would have to teach that to your applet's users :)

Comment: @JulioFaerman Regarding option 4, I think you can install an [extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/extensions.html) and add this line to the clients' deployment.properties file... Never done that though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for future readers - environment variable for applets:

_JPI_VM_OPTIONS

e.g.

_JPI_VM_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true