# How to bind Akka Http to ipv4 instead of ipv6?

Tags: scala, http, akka, bind, ipv6

I am writing an Akka Http server that binds to the localhost like this :

```
Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

where, `route` is a `Route`

The server is live. However, when I do

> lsof -Pn -i6

I get

```
java      15431 meghanraul  108u  IPv6 0x587291ab0e72f443      0t0  TCP 17.150.215.237:52165->17.179.152.251:443 (ESTABLISHED)
java      15431 meghanraul  114u  IPv6 0x587291ab031d5963      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

It is binding to ipv6 instead of ipv4. How do I make it bind to ipv4?

Comment: Where do you see it binding to IPv6? That is not shown in your `lsof` output. Despite the confusing `IPv6` label, it is clearly actually listening on IPv4 only.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I used netstat and lsof and the port and pid seems to be bound with an ipv6 label in both. Is there another command I could use ? Thank you for replying :)

Comment: Another command for what? Are you actually having a problem?

Comment: I need Akka Http to bind to ipv4. But it looks like it is binding to ipv6 according to netstat and lsof. Since you are saying it is clearly listenin to ipv4, how can I see that using a command line command ?

Comment: How about `ss -tnl` or something appropriate like that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is indeed using IPv6. Got the same problem, and `netstat` shows "tcp6" together with an IP address which looks like an IPv4 address. So the address is confusing.

Comment: @juanita In my case the system property `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` on the command line solved the problem (pure Akka remoting). Then it uses IPv4. Give it a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set preferIPv4Stack property for JNLP app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809919/how-to-set-preferipv4stack-property-for-jnlp-app)